# Access local parameters from module services and controllers

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3, zf3

I´m developing a site based on Zend Framework 3 and in some modules I need to send e-mails.

I´m using PERL Mail to do so. It willwill foward all e-mail send requests to Amazon SES service on production, and for development I´m using a free gmail account.

In my application I want to store the mail configuration in a local way using the `local.php` file at that `project/config/autoload directory`. In that way I can have different configurations for both development and production. So, I´ve created the following entries on my `local.php` file:

```
'mail' => [
   'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
   'port' => '465',
   'auth' => true,
   'username' => 'myusername@mydomain.com',
   'password' => 'mypassword',
]
```

All fine, except that I don´t know how to get these parameters from my modules services and controllers.

Here is a service example that I need to access this parameter, located at `module/User/src/service/UserManagerService`:

```
class UserManager
{
    /**
     * Doctrine entity manager.
     * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;  

    public function __construct($entityManager) 
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }


    public function addUser($data) 
    {
        **// Need to access the configuration data from here to send email**
    }
}
```

This service has a factory:

```
<?php
namespace User\Service\Factory;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use User\Service\UserManager;

class UserManagerFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {        
        $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

        return new UserManager($entityManager);
    }
}
```

I´m pretty new to these ZF3 factories, services and controllers, so I´m little lost here.

How can I get the parameters stored in the local.php file here at this service ? 
Would that approach be the same for a controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration is stored in the container under `Config`. You can retrieve it like you get a service or anything else from the container. This works for anything (services, controllers) you retrieved from the container with a factory. Best practice is to retrieve configuration options inside the factory and pass it to the service or controller.

Your factory:

```
<?php

namespace User\Service\Factory;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use User\Service\UserManager;

class UserManagerFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        $config = $container->get('Config');

        return new UserManager($entityManager, $config['mail']);

        /* Or write this as:
        return new UserManager(
            $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default'), 
            $container->get('Config')['mail']
        );
        */
    }
}
```

Your Service:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager

class UserManager
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $mailConfig;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, array $mailConfig)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->mailConfig = $mailConfig;
    }

    public function addUser($data)
    {
        var_dump($this->mailConfig);
    }
}
```